# Single NuGet transformation file for web.config and app.config

Tags: c#, nuget

NuGet has this nice feature of [transforming configurations](https://docs.nuget.org/create/configuration-file-and-source-code-transformations), which is widely used mostly for transformations in `web.config` or `app.config`.

Now in my scenario, I want to update the *main* config, no matter whether it's `web` or `app`, but I would also like to have just a *single source of truth*, e.g., just one file for install and uninstall in the package file.

Is that possible somehow? Any best practice?

Comment: Are you asking for a concrete solution? Or more of a guidance in what's possible? You can use powershell scripts for [automatic installation and removal of packages](https://docs.nuget.org/Create/Creating-and-Publishing-a-Package#automatically-running-powershell-scripts-during-package-installation-and-removal). I can image if you combine that with the transformations, you can create a *single source of truth*. I don't know about best practices though.

Answer (score 0):

You can just copy and rename the file before building a package. Of course, you should make some kind of a script for this task.

Comment: I'm clearly stating, that I'm not after such a solution: _I'm not expecting something like "convert x.config to both web.config and app.config", but a more elegant solution._ If there is non - well - then this question shouldn't get an answer.

Comment: OK, anyway, I don't see a problem. Why can't you store only one _app.config.install.xdt_ and one _app.config.uninstall.xdt_ (or _web_, it doesn't matter) and then just copy it to _web.config.install.xdt_ and _web.config.uninstall.xdt_ in a script before running package build? Actually, these operations should be in a single script. Apparently there can't be an other solution, the mechanism of package creation by itself is pretty simple.

Comment: @CalebKleveter looks like someone finds this answer helpful. And I think it provides a workaround.

Comment: @DmitriyDokshin: In my question I'm saying that I want a single file for install and uninstall. While this may seem a little vague - I meant single file in nupkg - I made things clear in the bounty description, saying that I don't want to _convert_! This bounty was put on the question for someone who has time for a little research. And as you may understand, your question is hardly what I was searching for, although it _might_ be helpful to some other people. I'm kindly asking you to remove your answer, and maybe convert it to a comment.

Comment: @Matthias OK, I got it.